# Select rows of dataframe whose column values amount to a given sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to find out how many of the first N rows of a dataframe make up (just over) 50% of the sum of values for that column.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 1), columns=list("A"))

0  0.681991
1  0.304026
2  0.552589
3  0.716845
4  0.559483
5  0.761653
6  0.551218
7  0.267064
8  0.290547
9  0.182846
```

therefore

```
sum_of_A = df["A"].sum()
```

4.868260213425804

and with this example I need to find, starting from row 0, how many rows I need to get a sum of at least 2.43413 (approximating 50% of sum_of_A).

Of course I could iterate through the rows and sum and break when I get over 50%, but is there a more concise/Pythonic/efficient way of doing this?

Comment: There is "cumsum" for a cumulative sum and (if column has no negative values) "searchsorted" to find the point where the sum is greater than a given value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `.cumsum()`, which we can use to get all the rows where the cumulative sum is at least half of the total sum:

```py
df[df["A"].cumsum() < df["A"].sum() / 2]
```

Comment: Very interesting idea but it seem to select the rows which go OVER the 50% value. Using the example above your code would select rows 5-9

Comment: Yes, did you want the rows under 50%? If so, change the `>=` to `<=`.

Comment: Yes thanks. The correct comparison for me is using '<'.

Comment: Got it. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it for the benefit of future readers. Have a great day!

Comment: If anyone's curious about the real use case, I have a dataframe with usernames in a column and the number of times they've commented in the other and have it sorted descending by this second column. With this I am selecting the first N users which have contributed to around 50% of the comments total :)